# Error in my javascript variable value when I change my screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my variable **page** and it will change when I click on **#next** button, and it's done successfully when I do `console.log`.

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
alert();
var page = "blank";
$(".billing-information").css("display", "none");
$(".services-information").css("display", "none");
$("#next").click(function () {
    page = "services";
    console.log(page);
    $(".personal-information").css("display", "none");
    $(".services-information").css("display", "block");
    nextFromPersonalInformationCss();
})
$(".back-from-billing").click(function () {
    page = "services"
    console.log(page);
    $(".services-information").css("display", "block");
    $(".billing-information").css("display", "none");
    backFromBillingCss();

})
$(".back-from-service").click(function () {
    page = "personal-ionformation";
    console.log(page);
    $(".personal-information").css("display", "block");
    $(".services-information").css("display", "none");

   backFromServicesCss();

})
$(".next-from-service").click(function () {
    page = "billing"
    console.log(page);
    $(".services-information").css("display", "none");
    $(".billing-information").css("display", "block");

     nextFromServicesCss();

})
```

Now my problem is that when I change my screen size it will always give me  "personal-information" value means at change of screen size it not stay stable

```
   $(window).resize(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
      //  alert(width);
        if (width <= 767) {
            console.log(page);
            if (page = "personal-ionformation") {
           //     alert("p")
                $(".personal-detail").css("display", "block");
                $(".services").css("display", "none");
                $(".billing").css("display", "none");
            }
            else if (page == "services") {
```

Comment: where i misspelt?

Comment: Just do a Find, you have misspelt it more than once.

Comment: @Flimzy I disagree. Just correcting without comment will confuse both the OP and other readers. I prefer just to point out the typo so everyone knows what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `if (page = "personal-ionformation")`,
you are performing an assignment, which alwayes returns `true`, change it to `if (page == "personal-ionformation")`. It may work.